# I want to creat a Text Field that take phone Number along country flags in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to creat a Text Field that take phone Number along country flags in iOS swift.like [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let using [PhoneNumberKit framework](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) that include all you need [image]

Comment: Thanks ! You are such a great person.